# Python: Not able to find error in my code. filenames returned by os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk

I have following directory structure:

```
DICOMs:
      Dir_1 
           /sub-dir 1
           /sub-dir 2
                   /file1.dcm
      Dir_2 
           /sub-dir 1
           /sub-dir 2
                    /file1.dcm
```

I have written following code to read **first file** of every sub_dir.

dire_str = '/DICOMs:/

```
for dirname,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(dire_str,topdown=True):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname,subdirname))
        a = 1
        for filename in filenames:
            firstfilename = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            dcm_info = dicom.read_file(firstfilename, force=True)
```

If i run this on python console it gives me

```
dirname = dir_1 
dirnames=[subdir_1, subdir_2]
filenames = .DSstore
```

FOr this error in filenames array i am not able to get filename of first file. Can some help me if there is error in code or if syntax is wrong ?
I have file1.dcm under subdir_2 and subdir_1. But still file shown is .DS_Store.

What i am trying to implement is:

```
1) go into Dir(say  dir_1)
   go inside subdir_1 
   look for first .dcm file to read header tag 
   if tag is present in first file (yes) then call a function which will excute code on this subdir.(note i want to check just first file)
   if not go out of this subdir
   in this way check every subdir

once done with one dir 
repeat these steps for dir2
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The output you posted can't be generated by the program you have written (also, it contains no errors). Please give us some realistic output and also explicitly state what you cannot understand. Perhaps, are you surprised to see a file named `.DS_Store`?

Comment: you're second for loop won't work. You probably need to call os.path.walk again or manually setup the second filenames loop. You're referencing variables defined before the first loop inside the nested loop. Doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you meant to do:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dire_str, topdown=True):
    # Do some stuff that is per directory
    for filename in filenames:
        # Do some stuff that is per file
        pass
```

And if you wish to only operate on files that end in `.dcm`, something along these lines might be good:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dire_str, topdown=True):
    # Do some stuff that is per directory
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.dcm')
            # Do some stuff that is per file
            pass
```

To specifically address the new bit of pseudo-code you added to the question, I believe you will want something like the following:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dire_str, topdown=True):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.dcm') and tag_present_in_dcm(
            os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        ):
            execute_code_on_subdir(dirpath)
            break
```

Comment: `.endswith()` exists, and is much nicer than using `[-4:]`, as this breaks as soon as you change `.dcm` to, say, `.dcmz`.

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini: my requirement is if .dcm file in not in that subdir i want to move out of that subdir and look for .dcm file in another subdir but under same dir. I want to check subdir one by one. is it possible? many thanks1

Comment: @tryeverylanguage that is what the second one will do. Each pass through the first level of the loop happens for each directory and subdirectory in the tree. The inner loop goes through each file name in a particular directory. So, for your example, top level executes for `DICOMs`, `DICOMs/Dir_1`, `DICOMs/Dir_2`, and `DICOMs/Dir_1/sub-dir 1`,  and finds nothing in each;  it then executes for `DICOMs/Dir_1/sub-dir 2` and finds **something**, and so forth. Modify the `dirnames` during the processing of each tuple if you want to exclude particular subdirectories from being recursed into.

Comment: @desfido Thank you for detailed explanation. i have edited my question again to list all requiremnets. I am very new to programming and hence finding hard to understand few steps or say debug what i wrote.